How can i calculate the surface Point of a given Object?
I'm implementing ray marching in GLSL to render spherical objects with surface point visualization. The issue occurs when viewing the objects from certain angles - the surface position calculation becomes incorrect.
Here's my fragment shader:
#version 400

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 color;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 CurrentPos;

uniform int sunCount;
uniform int planetCount;
uniform vec4 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightPos[64];
uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 sphereOrigin[64];
uniform float sphereRadius[64];

// SDF for spheres
float SDF(in vec3 p, in vec3 c, float r) {
    return length(p - c) - r;
}

vec3 calculateSurfacePos() {
    // Get normalized device coordinates (NDC) from gl_FragCoord
    vec2 uv_nds = (gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(1366.0, 768.0)) * 2.0 - 1.0;
    
    vec4 uv_clip = vec4(uv_nds, -1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 uv_eye = inverse(projectionMatrix) * uv_clip;
    uv_eye = vec4(uv_eye.x, uv_eye.y, -1.0, 0.0);
    vec3 uv_wor = (inverse(viewMatrix) * uv_eye).xyz;
    uv_wor = normalize(uv_wor);

    highp float t = 0.0;
    highp vec3 ro = viewPos;
    highp vec3 rd = uv_wor;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        highp vec3 p = ro + rd * t;
        float dist = 1e10;

        for (int j = 0; j < planetCount; j++) {
            dist = min(dist, SDF(p, sphereOrigin[j], sphereRadius[j]));
        }

        if (dist < 0.001) return p;
        if (t > 100.) break;

        t += dist;
    }
    return vec3(0.0);
}

void main() {
    vec3 surfacePos = calculateSurfacePos();
    FragColor = vec4(surfacePos, 1.0);
}

am getting this as output:

i want the sphere to be filled as i face it and not at certain angles

What I've Tried:
Implemented ray marching to find the intersection with multiple spheres using an SDF approach.
Normalized device coordinates to world coordinates correctly.
Used a loop to march along the ray until an intersection is found or a limit is reached.
Returned the intersection point if found, otherwise returned a default value.
Current Issues:
The surface position computed (surfacePos) is not providing the expected intersection points with the spheres. Instead, I'm getting unexpected colors or no intersections at all.
I’m unsure if my approach to calculating the ray direction and marching logic is correct.
Questions:
Is there any mistake in my transformation logic when converting from clip space to eye space to world space?
Are there any optimizations or best practices for ray marching that I should consider?
How can I debug the intersection points more effectively to ensure my SDF is returning the correct distances?

It seems that the position is directly used as a color, could it be that some XYZ/RGB-parts are negative and then clamped to 0, resulting in an "unexpected color"? The computation t += dist looks susceptible to floating point inaccuracies. Does the result improve when t is computed directly (t = i * dist)?

Your actually correct The computation t += dist looks susceptible to floating point inaccuracies. Thank you

So the way i was doing it i was sending a list of all planets position to the fragment shader but instead i needed to send them individualy and the list of all the planets why? Simple because for each planet we need to check if there is an intersection within their ray direction so ultimately my theory was to check where the ray would intersect with the UV coordinates but later i find out that it was because of the  computation t += dist looks susceptible to floating point inaccuracies.
vec3 computeShadow(in vec3 lightPos) {
    float t = 0.0;
    vec3 ro = lightPos;
    vec3 rd = normalize(sphereOrigin - lightPos);

    float maxDistToSphere = length(lightPos - sphereOrigin) - sphereRadius;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100 && t < maxDistToSphere; i++) {
        vec3 p = ro + t * rd; // Position along the ray
        float minDist = 1e9;

        // Check to each sphere (planet)
        for (int k = 0; k < planetCount; k++) {
            vec3 toPlanet = normalize(spheresOrigin[k] - lightPos); 

            // Check if the planet is roughly in the ray direction
            if (dot(rd, toPlanet) > 0.99) { // Allowing a slight tolerance
                float dist = SDF(p, spheresOrigin[k], spheresRadius[k]);
                minDist = min(minDist, dist);
            }
        }

        // If the ray is close enough to a surface, consider it in shadow
        if (minDist < 0.01) return vec3(t / float(80) * 4.0); // Soft shadow effect
        
        t += minDist; // Step forward along the ray
    }
    
    // If no shadow encountered, return light
    return vec3(1.0);
}

the maxDistToSphere is the length between the sun and a planet point in the sphere
and in the if condition here if (dot(rd, toPlanet) > 0.99)
we check the direction of those planets if they align with the planet that we are currently checking if they are perfectly align we calculate their distance and return soft shadow if t reaches a distance higher than maxDistToSphere so no planet were in the same direction
